# Lexus HS 250h car; a/c noise from inside the car

Tags: ac, noise, car, fan, lexus

I am getting these kind of noise https://youtu.be/QhmK7oDX1tE

Any idea what's wrong?

**Car details**
Year : 2010
Model : Lexus hs250h

Its happening when I switch AC/Fan on and it last for 30 sec and then goes away. of course it also go away if I switch off the AC/Fan

Comment: What year?  Is there anything else you can add?  When this occurs, etc.  cheers!

Comment: added  more more details

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a plenum (ventilation duct) fan bearing is slowly going bad based on the sound from underneath and behind the glove box.

Comment: Definitely the fan.  Its either a bearing issue or its a wear issue at the motor's commutator brush interface.  You could remove fan from behind the glove box, add a few drops of oil to both sides of the motor's  bearings and retest, or just purchase and install a new fan motor.  Obviously oil won't help a commutator harmonic.  As repair jobs go, its pretty easy.